# GetComponentsInChildren<GUIText>().text - does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, unity, gui

My Slider GameObject has a GUIText child. I am writing a C# script that should change the text component in the GUIText, but instead of this I am getting:

***error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.GUIText[]' does not contain a definition for`text' and no extension method `text' of type`UnityEngine.GUIText[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)***

```
 public Slider timeSlider;
 int i = 5;

 timeSlider.GetComponentsInChildren<GUIText>().text = 'Some Text' + i;
 //timeSlider.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<GUIText>().text = 'Some Text' + i; // doesn't work either
```

From the documentation I understand that GUIText should have a 'text' variable - Would anyone know why ().text is invalid?

Thank you!

How the hierachy is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using `GetComponentsInChildren`, which as the error message tells you, returns an array of `Unity.GUIText` objects. That array doesn't have a `text` property. So you will probably want to iterate over the objects returned or use a different method for accessing the component(s).

Comment: Good point. I just tried with  ***timeSlider.GetComponentInChildren<GUIText>().text= "Some Text";*** and get a NullReferenceException... would you have a suggestion for accessing the GUIText component (exact hierarchy in question)?

Answer (score 0):

Script needs to run on the parent. Then use this:

```
  transform.FindChild("child name").GetComponent<GUIText>().text = "some Text";
```

Now why would you use GUIText and not just Text that is part of the new UI system is beyond me.